# Webdriver is not able to find element under subclass

Tags: selenium, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to find element "core_text savable core_valid_regex" but everytime I am getting some or the other error.

```
<form id="core_order_holder" onsubmit="return false;">
<table class="order_holder">
<tbody class="core_loader_holder">
<tr>
<td class="core_item_label">Personal number:</td>
<td class="core_item_content">
<span class="savable-wrapper">
<input class="**core_text savable core_valid_regex**" type="text" name="loginid" size="13" style="outline: medium none;">
<span class="savable">
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Till now I have tried the following approaches:

1. `WebElement PersonalNumber = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)) .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("order_holder"))).findElement(By.className("core_loader_holder")).findElement(By.className("core_item_content")).findElement(By.className("savable-wrapper")).findElement(By.className("core_text savable"));`
2. `WebElement E1 = PersonalNumber.findElement(By.className("core_loader_holder")).findElement(By.className("core_item_content"));`
3. `WebElement E2 = E1.findElement(By.className("core_item_content"));
   WebElement E3 = E2.findElement(By.className("savable-wrapper"));
   WebElement E4 = E3.findElement(By.className("core_text savable"));
   WebElement PersonalNumber = driver.findElement(By.className("core_text savable"));`
4. `WebElement PersonalNumber = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("core_text savable")));`
5. `WebElement E1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(PersonalNumber.findElement(By.className("core_loader_holder"))));`
6. `WebElement PersonalNumber = driver.findElement(By.className("order_holder") ).findElement(By.className("core_loader_holder")).findElement(By.className("core_item_content")).findElement(By.className("savable-wrapper")).findElement(By.name("loginid"));`

Please find below the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"core_item_content"}
Command duration or timeout: 82 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'PC239657', ip: '172.31.204.104', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=core_item_content}
Session ID: 1a8604de-4ec7-4a77-ba8b-b1590ae49ce6
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=34.0.5, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebElement.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:387)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:167)
    at Submit_Order.TrustlySubmitOrder(Submit_Order.java:237)
    at Submit_Order.main(Submit_Order.java:260)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"core_item_content"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'PC239657', ip: '172.31.204.104', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/291578/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5858848057389913831webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement(file:///C:/Users/291578/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5858848057389913831webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10283)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/291578/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5858848057389913831webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/291578/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5858848057389913831webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/291578/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5858848057389913831webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)
```

How to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the only `input` element in the form? Does it always have the same `name` attribute?

In that case, you can simply try:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.Name("loginid"));
```

Or:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#core_order_holder input"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: I just modified your code and it worked. 

WebElement PersonalNumber = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("loginid")));
  PersonalNumber.clear();

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to accept my reply as solution, so the question doesn't remain open. Thanks.